# How to get private key from dogecoin wallet android app

Tags: dogecoin

As title, I've got an encrypted string, which gives me `.org.dogecoin.production.blabla` (or something like this) after I use `openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in ENCRYPTEDFILE -out dogecoin-wallet-decrypted`

After browsing, some gives me the idea to go through BIP39. Anyway, actually I don't understand it, though I did find a 12 words Mnemonic code.

So what's next ? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to name the wallet specifically. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dogecoin.production.blabla doesn't exist.

Assuming you were using a fork of the `schildbach` wallet, the general procedure based on the most likely fork is:

https://github.com/langerhans/dogecoin-wallet-new/blob/1ee32cc/wallet/README.recover.md

Your trouble will arrive when you try to use `bitcoinj` to decode your protobuf.  You will want to find a fork that supports dogecoin.